# apache 2.4.7 (easyphp) vs 2.4.9 (wamp) compatibility?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp, easyphp

Recently I decided to make some improvements on my sadly abandoned website I've developed using easyphp. I tried to installed the last version of easyphp to be sure being up-to-date. Unfortunately the last version is not quite what I hoped for and decided to uninstall it and switch to wampserver.
My website is not working anymore though and after few analyzing I am sure this is from the version of apache being different or from wamp dealing with the apache options differently from easyphp (2.4.7 -> 2.4.9).

The problem seems to come from the .htaccess file (which worked nicely on easyphp), is one here have faced the same problem when changed from easyphp to wampserver ? or any suggestions where the problem could come from ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized the module rewriteEngine was not initialized...